# ReactNavigation & Redux: All screens rerender using a StackNavigator when redux state is changed

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I am using Redux with ReactNavigation on a React Native project.

In my specific case, users can navigate from a UserScreen to another UserScreen.

I want to keep the previous screen in the stack, so the user can navigate back to the previous screen. I'm using `this.props.navigation.push("UserScreen")` to push the new screen on the stack.

The problem is when navigating to second user screen, the redux store changes and as a result all previous user screen rerender with the new props.

When the user navigate back to the previous screen, it will see the same exact screen as the new screen, since all screens have been rerendered.

I would think this is a common problem since most apps allow users to navigate to the same screen with different data set.

**Solution**
So I am thinking to use `componentShouldUpdate` on all UserScreens and check if its the activeScreen `return true` other wise prevent rerendering and maintain the screen with no change.

Does anyone have a better solution? is there any sample code.

Comment: I have faced this problem myself, use pureComponent and also componentShouldUpdate to restrict the component to render on specific state or props

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit late but hope this will help another ones who have the same issues. Here is my solution.

1. When navigating to a screen, update something in navigation params to tell that screen was focused and disable the focused status of the rest.
2. In component check focused status before render.

Sample code:

```
SideMenuNav.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
const { routeName } = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index];
navigation.state.routes.forEach((route, ind) => {
    if (!route.params) route.params = {}
    if (ind === navigation.state.index) route.params.isFocused = true
    else route.params.isFocused = false
})
```

See more at:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/redux-integration.html

https://medium.com/async-la/a-stately-guide-to-react-navigation-with-redux-1f90c872f96e

Answer (score 0):

if you have the same `reducer` added in your `connect` in all views cause this problem. The recommendation is to divide your reducers very intelligently to avoid this problem.

In some cases it can not be avoided, so it's necessary to resort to 2 solutions that if applied to time, greatly improve the performace in the application.

- **componentShouldUpdate**
- **[selectors](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect)**.

`pureComponent` it's also recommended, but it does not make a big difference in my case.

Example for `shouldComponentUpdate`:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps: Props) {
    if (objectNotEquals(this.props.items, nextProps.items) || (this.props.collectionLooksSelected !== nextProps.collectionLooksSelected) || objectNotEquals(this.props.executingRequest, nextProps.executingRequest)) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
```

`selectors` examples can be found in the link that i put above.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yes, I have broken up my reducers to small memoizable reducers using selectors, my specific problem is when the state of a screen changes, don't want previous screens in the stack to get updated.

Since all previous screens are the same screen, I think the only way to prevent that is using `shouldComponentUpdate` and return false in case if its not the active screen.